# (js) passing whole object into onclick method rather than a string

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="rating" onclick="swapImg('bad')"><img id="bad" class="unselected" src="img/unrated.gif"/></div>
```

my javascript is passing the entire img object into `swapImg`, and not the string 'bad.' for example, if i `console.log(param)` the param being passed into `swapImg`, i get:

```
<img id="bad" class="unselected" src="img/unrated.gif">
```

what is happening???

```
function swapImg(imgId) {
    console.log(imgId);
    var image = document.getElementById(imgId);
    console.log("success2");
}
```

Comment: Please post your 'swapImg' function

Comment: What is param? Have you changed your code since you posted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your function and HTML and it worked fine.

Even the `this` variable would be set to the `div` not the image. Is it possible you have any additional handlers somewhere else on the page? Or possibly have a stray `onclick` event on the `img` tag itself?

I tested in Firefox 3.5. Judging by the fact that your syntax is correct, something else is causing this to fail other than what you have posted.

You can [see my test here](http://jsbin.com/itapu). In Firefox or Safari (in developer mode) click the red div, and the console will show:

```
bad
success2
```